# Is Google Drive compliant with control A.8.15 in ISO 27001:2022?

Tags: compliance, certification, iso27001

Is Google Drive compliant with control A.8.15 in ISO 27001:2022?

As ISO 27001 requirements for logging and monitoring, are Event logging, Log storage, Protection of logs, and Analysis of logs, could I use Google Cloud as it is keeping this info in the history of the file?

We are dealing with experts and consultant, however, this question seems to be a grey area.

Comment: "in the history of the file" -- that's not a log. I think we need more detail. Do you have a personal account or a business account? Are there main Drive audit logs available to you? Or are you only talking about the "changes" log in the sidebar (that's not a log). And, as always, the decision is entirely up to the auditor.

Answer (score 0):

If Google is your vendor then they should be able to provide their most recent SOC2 and ISO cert. Either will describe the controls you are looking for once you download from [here](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/compliance-reports-manager).

I'd be surprised if they didn't have an audit function available to your workspace admin.

However, if you're speaking of that "activity" blurb on the sidebar of a personal account then that would be completely insufficient. Not even a grey area. You would have no control over record retention, audit function or even basic attributes expected of logging like unauthorized activity or host IDs. I would wholly expect to receive a finding and/or comment regarding non-compliance.